# Relation between LIR and an AS

Tags: routing

Someone can explain me what relation there is between a LIR and an AS? Can LIR assign AS numbers or only RIR can?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're talking about the AS-numbers defined in [RFC6696](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6996) meant for private use (64512 - 65534), all AS-numbers are assigned by RIRs to their LIRs.